# Element-wise multiplication of a 3D array with a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a `portion` of a RGB image as numpy array, the `shape` of which is `(height, width, channel) = (5, 5, 3)`.

What I want to do with this is to get the sum of element-wise multiplication with 5x5 `kernel` matrix, channel by channel. So it should yield a vector of size 3.

My current solution is:

```py
print(portion.shape)  # (5, 5, 3)
print(kernel.shape)  # (5, 5)
result = [(kernel * portion[:, :, channel]).sum() for channel in range(3)]
print(result.shape)  # (3,)
```

How can I achieve the same result in a more efficient way, hopefully without for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show here two methods of doing this. The first one is basically the "manual" version that relies on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which is an important concept to understand  for using `numpy` and similar libraries.

The second method is basically using the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), which can be quite fast if used right.

```python
import numpy as np
portion = np.zeros((5, 5, 3))
kernel = np.zeros((5, 5))
# alternative
result = np.sum(kernel[..., None] * portion, axis=(0,1))
print(result.shape)
# einsum method:
result = np.einsum('ij,ijk->k', kernel, portion)
print(result.shape)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwDIbve4qAh3VSiyJehPkIvoB4KBhYtjUtbSfOl68d1YMo5JJ8yffHzbGzvE@JjLM@Ak/GzaADsKuWAVmGNjfqid4GIQ4Scu2bphrQM44/MJMV6DFmqiPdsfIYpjGWvTAZUe4uSikJZ8t4hTW8kyToB4VWbOUua5wnjqKcq9Bph4saibMFDOa/b8cve0Gipl5SP2xOQy2hpMlPwn9rSi8)